# Are "left" and "right" unsemantic CSS class names?

Tags: css, class, layout, semantics, semantic-markup

According to [one author](http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/), using class names such as "left" and "right" is unsemantic CSS, but some of the comments suggest otherwise.

It makes sense that there could be some situations (e.g., mobile displays, design tweaks) where the "left" might not be so left anymore.

On the other hand, if the classes were called "address" and "phone" instead (to match the content), then that would solve it. But what if the content changed, or was slightly modified and no longer fit the bill?

Where is the common ground on this? Are there alternate, future-proof solutions that are semantic?

Comment: This calls for opinions and extended discussion and cannot be answered meaningfully as a technical question, especially since the word “semantic” is undefined and its relevance is unclear.

Comment: I disagree, things can be either semantic or not. By the way, [semantic is defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is fine because you are describing layout and layout needs those terms.

The 'semantic argument' is more for things like a 'red' tag when you want to highlight.  What happens when you want blue?  Better to have the tag be 'SuperImportant' and change it's color one place rather than 'red' and having to change it in every place (or even worse, changing what color 'red' points to and not changing the name.

So for left and right, they're probably better staying left and right.  I doubt these are gonna become 'top' and bottom' panels and I doubt they'd be repositioned as any thing else.

Note that this is for layout though.  If there is particular content that applies to the left and particular content that applied to the right, and n'er the twain shall meet, then also surround the content with tags, e.g. `<dems>lllll</dems>............<reps>- - - - - - </reps>`

Comment: Thanks. It's funny you mentioned that, in the example I have in my mind, these two panels are actually on top of each other on narrow viewports, but next to each other everywhere else.

Comment: Sure.  Yeah I'd probably do names for the data represented regardless of device then I'd have layout specific to each device for actual 'layout' itself using these or additionally added tags.

Answer (score 1):

In general, class names like "right" and "left" are not semantic unless the content itself has something to do with right or left (say, political parties or left-handed scissors).

I wouldn't worry too much about it.  Some people get so wrapped up in these kinds of talmudic debates about what is and isn't semantic that they lose their sense of proportion.

Comment: Thanks. Your second paragraph has a lot of truth in it. I'm still curious to hear what people come up with :P